# java Calendar class shows different time than linux system time

Tags: java, timezone, dst

Using a RHEL system, with java 7.

```
$ java -version
java version "1.7.0_72"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_72-b14)
Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM (build 24.72-b04, mixed mode)
```

`date` command output is as below:

```
$ date
Tue Aug  4 08:48:08 METDST 2015
```

However, with the below Java program, I get the time **exactly 1 hour less**.

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.TimeZone;

public class TimeInfo
{

  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    SimpleDateFormat fmt = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
    System.out.println("DateTime = " + fmt.format(cal.getTime()));

    TimeZone tz = Calendar.getInstance().getTimeZone();
    System.out.println("Time zone is: " + tz.getDisplayName() + ", timezone id = " + tz.getID());
    System.out.println(" DST = " + tz.getDSTSavings());

  }

}
```

Output:

```
DateTime = 08/04/2015 07:48:13
Time zone is: GMT+01:00, timezone id = GMT+01:00
DST = 0
```

The system is under daylight saving (as seen from date command output). However, the java Calendar class is not able to capture this. Tried to print the timezone, timezone id, DST etc -- but they are not able to capture that DST is in effect.

How this issue be solved programmatically (and without hardcoding the timezone name in the program)?

Comment: Found this on google, might help: [How to get java Date with Daylight savings](http://www.coderanch.com/t/487596/java/java/java-Date-Daylight-savings)

Comment: @BackSlash: Sorry, the solutions described there don't work for me. One hardcodes the timezone (which I don't want), another calls getTimeZone() of calendar which is already not working in my code.

Comment: There have been a handful of Java bugs (such as [this one](http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=6456628)) related to choosing the default time zone on various Linux distros.  Please update your JRE to current version and see if the problem persists.

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `Calendar`,  `SimpleDateFormat` and `TimeZone`. Those classes are poorly designed and long outdated, `SimpleDateFormat` in particular notoriously troublesome. Instead use `ZonedDateTime`, `DateTimeFormatter` and `ZoneId`, all from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Answer (score 2):

Strings such as `METDST` are not time zones. They are vague indicators of Daylight Savings Time (DST) being in effect or not in an area. But they are not standardized, and are not even unique. On top of that, I could not find any reference to a `MET` or `METDST` area.

Use [real time zones names](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones). They are in format of `Continent/Region`.

You are using terrible date-time classes that are now supplanted by the modern *java.time* classes defined in JSR 310. Never use `Date`, `Calendar`, and `SimpleDateFormat`.

Among the many problems with these legacy classes is the `Date#toString` method. That class stores a moment as seen in UTC, but its `toString` method implicitly applies the JVM's current default time zone while generating its text. This is an anti-feature, creating the illusion of a time zone being stored in the `Date` when in fact there is not. (Even worse, there *is* a time zone buried in that class, but is irrelevant to our discussion.)

I'm not sure as to your issue since I do not know the actual time zones involved. But the issue may be related to the JVM having a different default time zone than the host OS. The lesson to learn here: **Work in UTC.** Think of UTC (an offset of zero hours-minutes-seconds) as the one true time. Other time zones are but a mere variation. Your logging, debugging, data-exchange, and default time zones should be in UTC. Keep a second clock on your desk set to UTC (seriously).

## Use *java.time*

The *java.time* classes are built into Java 8 and later. You appear to be using Java 7. For Java 7, you can get most of the *java.time* functionality by adding the *ThreeTen-Backport* library to your project. Find links below in this Answer.

### Current moment

Capture the current moment as seen in UTC using [`Instant`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Instant.html) class.

```java
Instant instant = Instant.now() ;
```

Generate text in standard ISO 8601 format.

```java
String output = instant.toString() ;
```

Adjust into a time zone to get a [`ZonedDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html) object.

```java
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Edmonton" ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdt = instant.atZone( z ) ;
```

Our variables above, `instant` & `zdt`, represent the same moment, the same point on the timeline. They differ in their wall-clock time, the perception of date and time-of-day that vary around the world by time zone.

### Daylight Saving Time

Your code was trying to check to see if Daylight Saving Time (DST) was in effect or not. For that, use [`ZoneRules`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/zone/ZoneRules.html) from a time zone [`ZoneId`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/ZoneId.html) object.

```java
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "Africa/Tunis" ) ;
ZoneRules rules = z.getRules() ;
boolean isDaylightSavingInEffectNow = rules.isDaylightSavings​( Instant.now() ) ;
```

---

## About *java.time*

[image: Table of all date-time types in Java, both modern and legacy]

The [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes. Hibernate 5 & JPA 2.2 support *java.time*.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), [**Java SE 11**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_11), and later  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.

  - [**Java 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9) brought some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Most of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android (26+) bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), a process known as [*API desugaring*](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support#library-desugaring) brings a [subset of the *java.time*](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) functionality not originally built into Android.

    - If the desugaring does not offer what you need, the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above) to Android. See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).